# Batch file to download data from url

Tags: file, url, batch-file, download, local

The website link is http://www.nrldc.in/WBS/DrwlSch.aspx?dt=%DATE%&st=DELHI .
required a batch code to download the data from the URrl .

OR how can I download the data from URL through Batch file

Anyone please help

Tom

Comment: check bitsadmin -> http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html

Answer (score 1):

to do this you must use an external msdos application such as curl or wget!
and example would be:
    "%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\Update.zip" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/0kafa8pmnz6wivn/Update.zip
you can get wget from:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Answer (score 0):

**[How can I download a file with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)**

My attempt to resume ways of how file can be downloaded on windows.