# How can I download a file with batch file without using any external tools?

Tags: .net, jscript, wsh, batch-file

First to clarify this question is aimed to HTTP(s) download .For FTP  may be I'll ask (and answer) another question.
Here are [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url)  - but I want to be more precise .

Besides excluding external tools I want the solution(s) to be applicable for the widest possible types of windows machines (including XP,Win2003,Vista which still have big enough share).
Also as `WSH` is one of the possible options I prefer no using of temp files and everything to be packed in a single `.bat` file (which is possible with both jscript and vbscript).

What are possible approaches.

1. "Pure" batch solution with [BITSADMIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753856.aspx) - a command line utility
   available on every windows machine .It's not pretty convenient but is an/the only option where
   no other scripting language should be used.
2. Using WSH - Three approaches are possible - [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx) , [MSXML2.XMLHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx)
   ,[InternetExlorer.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx) - all of them are accessible ActiveX
   objects in order of how I prefer them.WinHTTP and  MSXML2.XMLHTTP
   are pretty similar in their capabilities but WinHTTP has a
   reputation of more stable.InternetExlorer.Application is in fact
   just the Internet explorer accessible through ActiveX object and
   some UI elements are unavoidable (are they?) so I'll skip this one.
3. Using .NET - It's possible to create a hybrid batch file with all
   the three default .NET compilers (Jscript.net , VB.Net , C#) with
   Jscript.net there is no redundant error messages so I'll prefer
   it.If we ignore the fact that there's a compiled .exe all the code
   is in one file ,so according to me this fits in the requirements :-)
   .With .NET we can use System.Net.WebClient or
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest (the WebClient relies on it) or
   System.Web.HttpRequest , but for now I'll post only
   System.Net.WebClient solution.And even more same ActiveX objects
   accessible with WSH are available here too.So there are really many
   ways to dowanload a file with .Net.May be in the future I'll update
   my answer.Anyway only the Webclient is especially designed for download.
4. Using powershell - has same possibilities as .NET but with less
   chances to be installed on all machines you can meet.So I'll skip
   this one too.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The answers.All scripts should be saved with `.bat`/`.cmd` extensions and can be used directly as batch scripts.

1. [**Certutuil**](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/A+Suspicious+Use+of+certutilexe/23517/) (for some reasons in the newest win10 builds this is recognized as trojan thread ):

   certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" pstools.zip

for easiness a macro can be used:

```
set "download=certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f"
%download% "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" pstools.zip
```

[CertUtil](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) command can be abused to download a file from internet.Available by default in windows since Vista.For WinXP Server 2003 Administration Tools are needed.

2. **Bitsadmin** :

simplest possible way to use it

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal http://downloadsrv/10mb.zip c:\10mb.zip
```

with macro:

```
set "dnld=bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal"
%dnld% "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" %cd%\pstools.zip
```

or with [**bitsDownloader.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/network/bitsDownloader.bat)

```
call bitsDownloader.bat "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" pstools.zip
```

3. [**winhhtpjs.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) is a command line http client that uses [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) .It can perform whole range of http (POST,DELETE,..) requests and can be used for downloading of files too (not too big files).Also custom headers can be added.

```
call winhhtpjs.bat "https://example.com/files/some.zip" -saveTo "c:\somezip.zip"
```

4. [**XMLHTTPDownloadJS.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/XMLHTTPDownloadJS.bat) is bat file that uses [MSXML2.XMLHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms759148(v%3Dvs.85)) object to download a file . Does not offer so rich options as [winhhtpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) , though is still an option.

   > call XMLHTTPDownloadJS.bat "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip pst2.zip"  pstools.zip
5. [**WebClientDownload.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/WebClientDownload.bat)  uses the .NET [System.Net.WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) class. It creates a small exe file in order to selfcompile itself and requires an installed a .net framework. As the class is presented in the very earlier versions of .net it is backward compatible enough

```
call webclientDownload.bat "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" pstools.zip
```

6. With the latest builds of windows 10 we have the [**CURL**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409) command ,though this is not so backward compatible option. Mind that only the newest versions of windows has CURL installed by default.

   > curl  "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" --output pstools.zip

Comment: Can `bitsadmin` be used to download every file on a webpage?

Comment: @Argyll - rather you'll need a program with web page crawling capabilities like wget (far more powerful than everything here )

Comment: I figured. I couldn't get Wget to do that. (It returns a bunch of random characters followed by "Permission Denied". That's why I asked.

Comment: @The WSH JScript has multiple issues.
`WScript` is case sensitive, -saveTo is used as an unnamed argument,
`XMLHTTPObj` sometime mispelled `WinHTTPObj`. 
I also suggest you to use `WScript.ScriptName` to make simpler the direct cscript call.

Comment: Dont forget the powershell command `(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('Source, Dest')`. Works on powershell v2 and not tested v1. It's the only script that can download files on OS's with PS's & CMD's that low.

Comment: @npocmaka hi, so, who can I get only last-modified date from file, not download them with you answer/code?  thx anyway, sorry my /en.. .

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe - you'll first need to download information about the files modification dates. But you'll have to check if the server provides such an information.

Comment: I found I needed the `/dynamic` switch. For example: `bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /dynamic /download /priority foreground https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/latest/download/cpptools-win32.vsix %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\cpptools-win32.vsix`

Comment: I note that the "Modified Date" is not the time of download; as it is for all simple browser downloads. (In case you're looking for the file you just downloaded :)

Comment: I tried certutil and bitsadmin, and both worked well. Certutil seemed to go faster. Thank you.

Comment: These days `certutil` will give *Access is denied* error. For macro, use `doskey`

Answer (score 2):

There's a utility (resides with CMD) on Windows which can be run from CMD (if you have write access):

```
set url=https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg
set file=file.jpg
certutil -urlcache -split -f %url% %file%
:also certutil.exe -verifyctl -f -split %url% %file%
```

Cmdlets in Powershell:

```
$url = "https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg"
$file = "file.jpg"
$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -outfile $file
```

.Net under PowerShell:

```
$url = "https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg"
$file = "file.jpg"
# Add the necessary .NET assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
# Create the HttpClient object
$client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient
$task = $client.GetAsync($url)
$task.wait();
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($file, $task.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result)
```

C# Command-line build with csc.exe:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DownloadImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var url = "https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg";
            byte[] imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

            using var fs = new FileStream("file.jpg", FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        }
    }
}
```

Built in Windows applications. No need for external downloads.

Tested on Win 10

Comment: thanks. The issues with certutil are something new. Now it is detected as a thread.

Comment: `Certutil` write access by default is now only given to *TrustedInstaller*, after viruses abused it to download exe, pif, vbs & bat files.
https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/87cf118bff58c38bc0d54c1d3fcc553e381df838437a99a2006dd8f726406c16?environmentId=100

Comment: what advantage `certutil` has compared to `cURL` and `BitsAdmin`? You can use them also to download stuff...

Comment: `certutil` works with certificates, pfx files, crypto keys, registry, roots, active directory, policies, caches, databases, encode files (to avoid detection by antivirus), in addition to downloading files & certificates so may have been a popular choice for virus & malware

Comment: To avoid further detection, `certutil` can also hide executables in alternate data streams of ordinary files eg. `trustme.txt`