# MS-DOS Command Variable URL download

Tags: variables, batch-file, auto-increment, str-replace

Hello I'd like to create a BATch-file to download a mp3 file with a increasing variable parameter URL that change daily. I've tried to use "bitsadmin" command but I've to replace different variables like "year", "month", "day", "series".

Any ideas how to do it?

```
bitsadmin /transfer grlavoro /download /priority normal http://www.radioarticolo1.com/userdata/media/audio/2015/03/20150331grl1800_54986.mp3 d:\grl.mp3
```

Is it possibile to do something like this?

```
@ECHO ON
set series=54986

set /a c=1

FOR /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (%series%) do (
set /a c=c+1
echo %%i,  %c%
)

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date

:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof

bitsadmin /transfer grlavoro /download /priority normal http://www.radioarticolo1.com/userdata/media/audio/%yy%/%mm%/%yy%%mm%dd%grl1800_%series%.mp3 d:\grl.mp3
```

Comment: @SoheilHashemi - that doesn't even remotely address his problem; he's trying to change variables so that he can download all of the episodes of some radio program.

Comment: Is that code something that you've tried and it isn't doing what you want?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools

Answer (score 0):

It's easier and less locale-dependent to set your date variables from `wmic os get localdatetime`.

```
for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list ^| find "="') do set "%%I"
set "YYYYMMDD=%localdatetime:~0,8%"
set "YYYY=%YYYYMMDD:~0,4%"
set "MM=%YYYYMMDD:~4,2%"
```

Also, it's generally preferable to use the powershell `BitsTransfer` module rather than `bitsadmin`, since the latter is deprecated and likely to be removed in future versions of Windows.  As a side benefit, you get a nice curses-style progress bar with the powershell command.

```
set "URL=http://www.radioarticolo1.com/userdata/media/audio/%YY%/%MM%/%YYMMDD%grl1800_%series%.mp3"
powershell "Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer %URL% d:\grl.mp3"
```

I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you're trying to do with your `%series%` variable.  Under what circumstances, and how many times, do you intend to increment it?

I had a look at the website you're leeching.  Although I don't understand Italian, I did come across the [podcast archive page](http://www.radioarticolo1.it/jackets/audio.cfm).  All the podcasts offered for download are served by a ColdFusion script accepting an incrementing numeral in the query string.  There's no date manipulation needed if you use their audio_download.cfm script.  Would it be preferable for you to use that, so you don't have to try to pair the date with a series number?  (You're the Italian language expert in this thread.  I'm genuinely asking.)