# Windows Bitsadmin Alternative

Tags: batch-file, microsoft-bits

because Bitsadmin is getting deprecated I would like to hear if you know about an alternative to Download files from within a batch script.
Best would be an alternative that already comes with windows so I don't need to download extra stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bacon Bits and I had the same idea at the same time.  Here's an example using PowerShell's `BitsTransfer` module.  Save this as a .bat file and run it.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "URL=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg"
set "SaveAs=sprites.svg"
powershell "Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer '%URL%' '%SaveAs%'"
```

Comment: I would suggest that it's better to just use PowerShell directly so that you don't need to write and save a batch file.

Comment: Syntax for executing a powershell script: `powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned ".\basename.ps1"`.  Syntax for executing a batch script: `basename`.  Gui method for launching a powershell script: Right Click --> Run with Powershell.  Gui method for launching a bat script: Double click.  Writing and saving a batch file often results in a nicer user experience, Bill.

Comment: I recommend running PowerShell commands directly from a PowerShell command window rather than double-clicking from a GUI window.

Answer (score 3):

Good news -- [BitsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bitsadmin-tool) isn't being deprecated.

(I work for the BITS team at Microsoft)

Comment: why is it so slow compared to wget?

Comment: Other questions that are more relevant: why does wget download over my cell connection? I was roaming and the bill was much more than I expected!

Or, "when I run wget, suddenly all my other apps run more slowly! How come?"

Or, "I was downloading with wget, and rebooted. Why did the download stop?"

BITS is designed to be a background downloader: it knows about power states, the cost (at least roughly) of your connection, and more. And it can handle reboots, restarting the downloads. 

Wget is designed to handle a surprising number of network protocols in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

The best alternative to `BITSAdmin.exe` is to [use PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382721.aspx).

If you cannot use PowerShell, you're pretty much stuck with `copy`, `xcopy.exe`, and `robocopy.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I download a file with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)   - you can check this

Probably the powershell is the best alternative Though you still can find vista and XP machines without powershell - if portability is important for you 
go to WSH.

.I don't think MSXML2.XMLHTTP and WinHTTPRequest ([here I've a little bit more powerful tool based on winhttprequest](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat)  - and more tested ) are going to be deprecated any time soon but they will require WSH or jscript or vbscript or powershell.

jscript.net and webclient will work better for bigger files.