# Download image from a website using Batch

Tags: batch-file, microsoft-bits

I have a .bat file that is supposed to download an image from a website and save it somewhere on your computer using Bitsadmin, 
but whenever I try to run it, I get this error:

```
DISPLAY: JOB TYPE: DOWNLOAD STATE: ERROR
PRIORITY: NORMAL FILES: 0 / 1 BYTES: 0 / UNKNOWN
Unable to complete transfer.
ERROR FILE:    http://website.com/pictures/picture.png -> C:\
ERROR CODE:    0x80190194
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005
```

I honestly have no idea what that means so I would love some help with it.
Here is my current code (The website in the real code is something else, this is just an example)

```
@echo off && set /p name=Name: 
bitsadmin /transfer job /download /priority normal C:\Users\user\Downloads\%skin%.png c:\%name%.png
pause
```

Thanks.

Comment: Download cURL or wGet.

Comment: Error code 0x80070005 is also known as "ACCESS DENIED." - You may have a wrong save path or don't have write permissions.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks! That did it, but now the error has changed to 0x80190194

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools

Comment: @PedroLobito Nevermind! Fixed it! The website itself had capitalization in its domain that I didn't put in the bat file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I was trying to save it in a restricted save path.