# Not running bat file is not looking for files

Tags: batch-file

Good day. tell me how to implement a batch file had not worked. Batch file checks for the presence of the two files (2 txt file - 123.txt and 321.txt) to the C drive, after checking if they are, then remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly delete them without checking:

```
del /q /f "c:\123.txt" "c:\321.txt" 2>nul
```

If you want checking anyway:

```
if exist  "c:\123.txt" del /q /f "c:\123.txt" 
if exist  "c:\321.txt" del /q /f "c:\321.txt"
```

Comment: Many thanks! even if the prompt is not difficult. Next, after the removal of these files, the script must be downloaded from the Internet 123.txt Andes 321.txt and throw them on the C drive, any hosting.

Comment: @BecauseBecause - so you have troubles with internet downloadin?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)

Comment: @npocmaka, all these years and I never knew that command existed.  I scroll right by it on SS64 website just about every day. Banging me head!!!