# How to call batch file from internet on the command promt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've uploaded to the internet my batch file code. And I want to know if I can run this batch file (which is now on the internet) from my computer on the cmd. Is there a command to do this? I really don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Where did you upload your file?

Answer (score 0):

you must first download it.You can use the [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) for that purpose:

```
call winhhtpjs.bat https://example.com/mybat.bat -saveTo "%cd%\mybat.bat"
call mybat.bat
```

or with bitsadmin (not every windows have it by default):

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://example.com/mybat.bat "%cd%\mybat.bat"
call mybat.bat
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools) you can see more options on how you can download a file

Answer (score 0):

You can download your file with powershell and batch and start it like this way :

```bat
@echo off
set "url=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3"
set "FileLocation=%userprofile%\Desktop\Matrix.mp3"
echo Please wait ... Downloding file is in progress ...
Call :PSDownload "%url%" "%FileLocation%"
start "" "%FileLocation%"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:PSDownload <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

Just change the URL and FileLocation variables to yours and test it ;)