# How can I make a batch file that downloads a file from Dropbox?

Tags: batch-file, cloud, dropbox, dropbox-api

How can I make a batch file that downloads a file from Dropbox?

Comment: why is the repeating?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shared link you can use any command line http client.
Here's example with [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) with a link from my dropbox :

```
winhttpjs.bat "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96959329/wtime.bat" -saveto wtime.bat
```

If you want to use user name and password you can try with:

```
winhttpjs.bat "https://www.dropbox.com/home/folder?preview=my.file" -saveto my.file  -user someone@mail.com -password superSecretPass
```

though you need to click on the file you want to see the link.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)

Comment: This might work with direct links however dropbox share links are not direct. the file will be saved with html code in it. A solution would be to use a direct link generator such as http://syncwithtech.blogspot.com/p/direct-download-link-generator.html