# Download a file from the internet and save to a location

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

```
$Interweb = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'downloads\filename.exe'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://urldownload.exe" -OutFile $Interweb
```

Currently the above works in PS v2.0 however im trying to run this on machines with a lower version. Is there a way to do this in PS v1.0?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools .

Comment: net webclient? https://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/11/using-powershell-to-query-web-site-information/

Comment: @4c74356b41 `New-Object` was introduced in v 2.0

Comment: sorry, I'm not a big expert in 1.0 :)

Comment: All Windows operating systems still supported by Microsoft can run at least PowerShell v2. I strongly recommend upgrading to at least that version instead of trying to work around limitations of v1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a file with batch file without using any external tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)