# Download files from Artifactory

Tags: windows, batch-file, artifactory

How can I download files from Artifactory . Is it possible to download using batch script . I used CURL commands to upload then on the same way please provide suggestions to download. Appreciate your help.

Comment: have you checked [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)?

Comment: Hi @npocmaka . I am trying to download it to Windows system.

Comment: did you use native curl or the powershell alias for curl (which is in fact HTTPRequest)?

Comment: If you use native curl I guess you did curl -X POST ... then you just have to rerun same curl command without -X switch and so use the default GET verb. If you use the alias have a look to this [link](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I used the same CURL command with Ansible .But I missed to configure the remote server for Ansible .So the CURL was not working . After configuring the remote server. It was able to download Thanks a lot for the response

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/getcli/) - a compact and smart client that provides a simple interface that automates access to JFrog products. The CLI works on both Windows and Linux.
 
For downloading files, take a look at the [command for downloading files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) from Artifactory. This command allows you downloading specific files, multiple files (using wildcards) or complete folders,

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU WGET from here - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
Very small utillity and supports download percentage and alot of other options like overwriting, not download if file exists etc.