# Download a file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How would I auto download a picture onto my PC using a batch file into the pictures section of my PC ?

I have already tried looking on Google and have found nothing !

Comment: Never mind thank you

Answer (score 2):

For example, i use a little function in powershell and with a batch file i can download a file like this one :

```bat
@echo off
Set "URL=http://www.kcc.edu/campaigns/PublishingImages/poh.jpg"
Set "File=%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Hello.png"
Call :Download "%URL%" "%File%"
Start "" "%File%"
exit
::**********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::**********************************************************************************
```

Here is another example where i used the same function to download the tool called **VirusTotal Uploader** from **Virustotal.com** to upload and check files.

***[Scan_Registry_Virustotal.bat](http://pastebin.com/VxiEzdxP)***

Answer (score 1):

[***Check this***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143180/388389).

with bitsadmin :

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal http://downloadsrv/jpg.jpg "%userprofile%\pictures\jpg.jpg"
```

with [***winhttpjs.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat):

```
call winhhtpjs.bat https://example.com/files/jpg.jpg -saveTo "%userprofile%\pictures\jpg.jpg"
```

Each users pictures directory is located in `%userprofile%\pictures`