# How can I download .exe file from Google Drive using bitsadmin.exe in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-10

I get error when I am trying to download .exe file from Google Drive using bitsadmin.exe in windows 10

I am using command below:

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer newJob https://drive.google.com/a/birdeye.com/uc?authuser=0&set id=1OhVx_wdInQYMnpWaDQeYou2zoJ0NMizE&set export=download C:\CCC\WinSCP.exe
```

Error:

```
C:\>bitsadmin.exe /transfer newJob https://drive.google.com/a/birdeye.com/uc?authuser=0&set id=1OhVx_wdInQYMnpWaDQeYou2zoJ0NMizE&set export=download C:\CCC\WinSCP.exe

BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright 2000-2006 Microsoft Corp.
 BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
 Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.

 Invalid argument.
```

Comment: Not understanding what you are trying to do with the two `SET` commands. I suggest you read the extensive help for [Bitsadmin](https://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html). There is an example on how to download a file.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs) for the BITS PowerShell cmdlets

Comment: Are the ampersand symbols meant to be part of the URL or are you really trying to do more than one thing on a single line?

Comment: May be you'll find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools) useful. What's the exact link you want to download form? Are you trying to set some headers or url parameters with these `set`s?