# I'm trying to embedded batch into php, but it is not executing

Tags: php, batch-file

So, I'm trying to setup a batch executable inside a website (php in this case), so it would download certain file directly to desired directory, without need for user to interact with it. Basically the plan is if there was a website with mods/in-game builds/worlds for a game, you'd want to download them directly into AppData, and not bother with moving it from Downloads manually.
I am using Xampp localhost to test run it (and I did run it as admin).

I searched up online to find how to embed batch inside php, and got to this:

```
<?php
    exec("cd %AppData% && curl <LINK> -o <NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX>");
?>
```

I tried with 'system' instead of 'exec', adding 'cmd /c' in front of the command as well, but not working either

I tried a different approach after that, just to test

```
<?php
    exec("start batch.bat");
?>
```

with this code

```
@echo
cd %AppData% 
curl <LINK> -o <NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX>
pause
```

Which resulted in

```
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried absolute path instead of relative, but no positive result either.

Now I don't know what else to try and what could be causing this. If there is another viable option to achieve what I've stated above, please do let me know as well.

Comment: curl is a program that needs to be on your computer. If you can't run these commands from your computer's command line they won't work when called from php like this either. Try installing [curl for windows](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/) and give it another go.

Comment: is `curl` in your path? from cmdline do `where curl` I suggest you rather give full path to curl in your batch file, if it is not in `C:\windows\system32` Like `c:\some dir\curl.exe`

Comment: If it is installed in your computer, try adding the full path to it, which is found if you run `where /r "C:" curl.exe` in cmd.

Comment: @double-beep `where /r` is not recommended here, the idea of running `where` is to see if the file is in path, if you recurse it, it will search for the file and will not solve the issue. technically, `curl.exe` defaults in `c:\windows\system32` which should be in path and should return by `where curl`

Comment: @gerhard-barnard It works when I run it directly from terminal, so it should be installed. I'll try with full path, tnx.

Comment: ok, let me know then, if it is in `c:\windows\system32` just run it as `curl.exe` another thing, is it needed to run `start batch.bat`? you should just be able to run `batch.bat` and lastly, confirm your batchfile is not actually named `curl.bat` or `curl.cmd`

Comment: Can you perhaps expalin why you're changing directory to `%AppData%`? Is `curl.exe` inside that directory?, If not, is that the intended location for the output file, `<NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX>`?

Comment: @gerhard-barnard It is in the said path, but even with the full path given, it gives the same error. I also tried adding ```where curl``` in that script and it doesn't find it either. Nope, if I remove 'start' it doesn't execute it. The batchfile I'm, using to test it is called ```test.bat```

Comment: @Compo yes that's correct, that's the location where I want to output file

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools/28143180#28143180

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot forget about changing directory, and just use `-o "%AppData%\<NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX>"`, then?

Comment: @Compo thanks for the idea, I'll use that. But ```curl``` still doesn't work nonetheless

Comment: @ShadowWolf01, I was merely simplifying your command, not providing an answer. Is this the command you say doesn't work? `exec("curl <LINK> -o \"%AppData:\=\\%\\<NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX\"");`

Comment: @Compo After modifying it by your suggestion, I'm using ```exec("curl <LINK> -o %AppData%\<NAME>.<FILE_SUFFIX>");``` now

Comment: @npocmaka I tried using ```bitsadmin``` from the list you sent, and it works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the working code I am using now

```
<?php
    exec("bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority high <LINK> <TARGET_LOCATION_FILE>");
?>
```

I still don't know why the `curl` didn't work, but as `bitsadmin` is native windows command, it's better anyway. Thanks to everyone who helped!