# How can i download stuff from my site via powershell and batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, download

So im storing a **.zip** file on my site's server, and i wanna use that to make a simple autoupdate program with batch and powershell. How can i do this?

The code i was trying to use: `powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "[site-ipv6]/ *path* /package.zip" -OutFile "C:\"`

Comment: I was a bit unclear, basically im trying to download a file with batch and powershell, sorry

Comment: check also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools