# Create a batch file for downloading an EXE from FTP Sever

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

How to create a batch file that supports almost all Windows OS for downloading an EXE file to a specified location and replace the existing EXE file from an FTP server having user authentication.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools

Comment: Do you known you could embed external exe tool directly into the batch file? On first bych runtime on specific machine batch test if tool already extracted, or extract it there.

Comment: @npocmaka Thank you for your replay. i tried "certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f "ftp://domainname.com/filename.exe"  filename.exe" , But it's not downloaded the file. Result Showing : "-URLCache command completed successfully." .

Comment: @Vishnu - then check the ftp command.

Answer (score -2):

You might wanna check out bitsadmin. It's able to download files from servers. Here's a link to a discussion on bitsadmin [bitsadmin discussion link](https://serverfault.com/questions/646836/how-to-use-bitsadmin-exe-windows-download-file-from-authenticated-jenkins-serv)

It tells how do use bitsadmin to download with a pass/user

Comment: bitsadmin is deprecated

Comment: @user2956477 - it's been "deprecated" for the last three versions of Windows. I don't believe it's going anywhere. That said, I'm downvoting because link-only answers should be discouraged.